# How can I create a XLS containing VBA code without using Excel

Tags: vba, excel, build, automation

Our application contains many XLAs, containing many forms, modules and code modules.

When we source control our software we would like to check in the textual elements of the XLA and then have a build process that creates our XLS/XLA files, ideally without automating Excel - we don't have it on the build server.

I've seen many components that create Excel workbooks, but have not seen one that can take a workbook and insert VBA and update references etc. Does anyone know if one exists?

Regards,

Comment: I'm not seen one on open market boss.  Your rival Swiss firm across the way built one themselves, a member of their staff now works for your firm, a Mr E Whipp.

Comment: No you cannot do that

Comment: Thanks Simon. I thought as much, I've not been able to find a comercial/open source one either.In that case I guess the only option is to write a command line utility to do it that wraps Excel